# How to perform parallel cross browser testing with selenium grid testng data provider

Tags: java, testng, selenium-grid, dataprovider, parallel-testing

I am trying to run a parallel test with chrome and Firefox using selenium grid and TestNG.

I am using @DataProvider to make it data driven with single excel file

However, one of the browser get closed every time I try to run my suite and throws the following error stack while one of the browser still functional running the test script successfully:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:1062)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:395)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:347)
at com.opta.ccf.helper.ExcelUtil.getCellData(ExcelUtil.java:90)
at com.opta.ccf.helper.ExcelUtil.getTableArray(ExcelUtil.java:56)
at com.opta.iclarify.test.TDAttTest.osbData(TDAttTest.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:137)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:430)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1274)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1079)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:400)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have the following Items in testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="suite1" verbose="1"  parallel="tests">
    <test name="firefoxTest">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <classes>
        <class name="TestAll" />
    </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="chrometest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="TestAll" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I have the following for the before test which is inside class called Framework being inherited by child class called TestAll:

```
@Parameters({"browser"})
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public  void setup(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {
    //Set the desired capabilities
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //Setting Desired Capabilities
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Internet Explorer")){
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setBrowserName("IE");
    }
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        caps.setCapability("marionette", true);
        caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
    }
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

        caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        caps.setBrowserName("chrome");

    }
    //Setting Browser

    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
        URL(parentPropFile.getProperty("ServerHubUrl")), caps);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

My data provider Method is as following which is inside child class TestAll inheriting Framework Class:

```
@DataProvider(name = "tdData")
public static Object[][] osbData(){
    Object[][] testObjArray = null;
    try {
        testObjArray = ExcelUtil.getTableArray("data-2.xlsx");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return testObjArray;
}
```

And My test method include the following which is inside child class TestAll inheriting Framework Class:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "tdData", threadPoolSize = 2)
public  void testTD(String streetName, String SteetNo,.......){
        try {
            //TEST SCRIPT
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`@DataProvider(name = "dataPro")`  and `@Test(dataProvider = "tdData", threadPoolSize = 2)`

The data provider passing to the test is different, hence it leads to issue. Generally, if we use `getStringCellValue` for Numeric cell then that exception will be thrown.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. However, I was able to resolve the issue based on the solution provided 

byhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724073/driver-behavior-executing-parallel-testng-selenium-tests-with-dataprovider?rq=1 

1) I created a separate class with data factory and data provider which call the constructor of the class with test methods using parameter provided through data provider. The solution is similar to the solutions proved in the following links.

http://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-executing-parallel-tests/
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was  but based on [Driver behavior executing parallel TestNG selenium tests with dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724073/driver-behavior-executing-parallel-testng-selenium-tests-with-dataprovider?rq=1)

to resolve this issue I did the following:

I created a separate class with data factory and data provider which call the constructor of the class with test methods using parameter provided through data provider.

The solution is similar to the solutions proved in the following links.

- http://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-executing-parallel-tests
- http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories